# Difference between Mat, MCvMat, Image, MIplImage, ScalarArray, Matrix in EmguCV4

Tags: opencv, emgucv

What is the difference between these types of image storage variables in EmguCV4, I'm really confused, Unfortunately there is no good training resource for EmguCV4, Even on the [EmguCV4 site](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Why should there be so many variables to store an image? When and where should we use which type of variable?

1. Mat, MCvMat
2. Image, MIplImage
3. ScalarArray
4. Matrix

Comment: Why don't you ask directly to their [forum](http://www.emgu.com/forum/)?

Comment: I asked on the above site, but my questions have not been confirmed yet, I think I have to wait a few days.